# ActionMailerのPreview起動時に、引数が間違っている（wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)）と怒られるので解消したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail

## 解決したいこと

HerokuSchedullerを使い、こちらが指定した時間で、rake taskを実行させたいのですが、実行させるメール送信機能のPreview（`test/mailers/previews/alert_mailer_preview.rb`）にエラーが発生しており、解決したいと考えております。

エラー内容：wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

userを引数として渡しているはずなのに、Preview画面では一向に変わらずお手上げ状態です。お力貸して頂けますと幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この後の **「send_alert」** をクリックすると、下記の通り、「引数が間違っている（wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)）」と怒られてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 環境

Ruby:2.6.5
Rails：5.2.4
DB:PostgreSQL
Heroku Scheduller

## コード

**mailers/previews/alert.mailer_previrew.rb**

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/alert_mailer
class AlertMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_alert(user)
    @user = user
    mail(
      to: @user.email,
      subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
    )
    # mail to: "#{@user.email}", subject: "Hello,#{@user.email}"
    # mail to: user.email, subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
  end
end
app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'noreply@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

**terminal**

```
Started GET "/rails/mailers/alert_mailer/send_alert" for ::1 at 2020-06-30 15:53:55 +0900
Processing by Rails::MailersController#preview as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"alert_mailer/send_alert"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):
  test/mailers/previews/alert_mailer_preview.rb:3:in `send_alert'

Started POST "/__better_errors/30c7823ed90f92ce/variables" for ::1 at 2020-06-30 15:53:55 +0900
```

**app/views/alert_mailer/send_alert.html.slim**
**app/views/alert_mailer/send_alert.text.html.slim**

```
= user.mail 様

この度は「TTManager」を利用頂きましてありがとうございます。
br/
練習記録の登録はお済みですか？お済みでない場合は、こちらからログインをお願い致します。
br/
= link_to 'https://vast-anchorage-69571.herokuapp.com/', do
  | ログインはこちら
  span
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, password_length: 6..128
  has_many :records

  def self.guest
    find_or_create_by(email: "guest@example.com") do |user|
      user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
          # user.confirmed_at = Time.now  # Confirmable を使用している場合は必要
    end
  end
end
```

**app/mailers/alert.mailer.rb**

```
class AlertMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_alert(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
    # mail to: "#{@user.email}", subject: "Hello,#{@user.email}"
    # mail to: user.email, subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
  end
end
```

Comment: ログはありますか？

Comment: `alert_mailer_preview.rb:3:in send_alert'` とあるので、肝心のエラーが出ている `alert_mailer_preview.rb` が 掲載されていないように思います。

Comment: Okuraさん、ご確認ありがとうございます。追記した通り、previewの引数(user)を消したらなぜかうまくいきました（しかし別のNo Methodエラーが発生している）。また、ログを記載致しましたので、ご確認頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: nakanishiさん、ありがとうございます。``preview.rb``は1番最初にUPしておりますが、**追記**にある通り編集すると、wrong_number~のエラーが解消できました。今は別のNo Method errorが出ている状況です。

Comment: @maiyanhahumetu `mailers/previews/alert.mailer_previrew.rb` なるほど。タイトルの名前が正しくないようですね。別のファイルかと思いました。正しい名前に修正をお願いします。

Comment: @maiyanhahumetu `AlertMailer.send_alert(@user)` で解決したのであれば、これは追記ではなく、ご自身で回答されるのがよいと思います。別に起こったエラーは別の質問にしたほうよいです。スタックオーバーフローは1つの質問に1つの答えになるように質問することが推奨されているためです。

Comment: @maiyanhahumetu https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67606/9008 こちらの回答にもあります通り、引用  `追加質問のやり方
スタックオーバーフローは質問者に利するためにとどまらず、他に類似の懸案で困っている技術者や学習者にも役立つためのQAサイトです。
そのため一つの質問が解決した時に発生した質問はコメントや質問を編集するのではなく、新しい質問を作成するようお願いいたします。`

あとから来た人にも内容がわかるように質問を編集して回答をつけていただくのがよいと考えております。ご協力をお願いいたします。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、まずは1つの質問に対して回答が得られれば、そこで終了とするように致します。ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。解決策なども、質問を編集する形で記載し今回のエラーについては自分で考えようと思います。＞ **別に起こったエラーは別の質問にしたほうよいです。スタックオーバーフローは1つの質問に1つの答えになるように質問することが推奨されているためです。**

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/274041

Comment: @maiyanhahumetu 修正ありがとうございます。自己解決した内容は質問に書くのではなく、回答欄に自分で投稿するのが良いです（自分で回答フォームに入力できるはずですがいかがでしょうか）。 `undefined method mail' for` の件は関係ないので、思い切ってごっそり消したほうが、あとから訪れる人には親切です。
ちなみに、`wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` というのは、`1つの引数を要求していますが、実際には0個しか渡って来なかった` という意味です。どこから　`send_alert`　が呼び出されているか不明ですが、その呼出箇所で引数に何も与えていなかったのがうまく動かなかった原因ですね。今回の解決方法は、引数を受け取らないようにしたので、呼び出し側と受け取り側で引数の数が一致（何も渡さないし受け取らない）したわけです。

Answer (score 1):

## 解決した方法

**mailers/previews/alert.mailer_previrew.rb** を下記のように変更すると、「引数が間違っている」というエラーが解消しました。別のエラー（No Method Error）が発生していますが、そちらは自分で解決策考えようと思います（nakanishiさん、ご指摘頂きありがとうございました）。

#### 修正前のコード

```
class AlertMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_alert(user)
    @user = user
    mail(
      to: @user.email,
      subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
    )
    # mail to: "#{@user.email}", subject: "Hello,#{@user.email}"
    # mail to: user.email, subject: '練習記録を登録しましょう！'
  end
end
```

#### 修正後のコード

```
class AlertMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_alert
    @user = User.all
    AlertMailer.send_alert(@user)
  end
end
```

#### やったこと

1. `alert_mailer_preview.rb` では 引数 `(user)` を消した
2. 全ユーザーへの送信をテストしたいと思ったので、`@user = User.all` に変更した
3. 他Qiitaの記事を見て、`Mailer.アクション名(引数)` と記載した